# project-chip/connectedhomeip Build error: "ninja: error: unknown target 'python'"

Tags: openthread

Cross post to try to find a solution.
https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/issues/15596

I think I am following the build instructions properly for the Matter configuration app on Pi but it is throwing this error.

Any advice?

```
pi@otbr:~/connectedhomeip $ scripts/build_python.sh -m platform -d true
Input values: chip_detail_logging = true , chip_mdns = "platform", enable_pybindings = false, chip_case_retry_delta=""

  WELCOME TO...

           ░▓░
           ▓█▓
           ▓█▓                                                     ▒█     ▒█
      ▒██▒▒▓██▒███▒                ░▒▓▒░  ░▒▓▒░       ░░▓█▒░ ░█  █████████████░    ░▒█▒░       ░░▒░
       ░▓█████▓██░               ▒█▒░░▒▓██▓▒░░▒█▒   ░█▓▒░░▒████    █▓░    █▓░    ▒█▒░░░▒█▓░   ██▒░░
    ▒█▒░         ░██▒           ░█░     █▓     ░█░ ░▓▒      ░▓█    █▓     █▓    ▒█░░    ░██  ▒▓
    ░▓██▓░     ░██▓█░           ░█      ▓█      █░ ░█░       ██    █▓     █▓    ▓██████████  ▒█
     ░▓███▒   ▒███▒░            ░█      ▓█      █░  ██░    ░███    █▓     █▓    ░█▒░         ▒█
 ░▒████████░ ░███▓▓█▓▓▒         ░█      ▒▒      █░   ░█▓██▓█░▒█    ░▓▓█░  ░▓▓█░   ▒▓▓██▓█░   ▒▓
 ░██▒░  ▒██▒ ▒██░  ░▒█▓
         ░▓░ ░▓░

  ACTIVATOR! This sets your shell environment variables.

Activating environment (setting environment variables):

  Setting environment variables for CIPD package manager...done
  Setting environment variables for Python environment.....done
  Setting environment variables for pw packages............skipped
  Setting environment variables for Host tools.............done

Checking the environment:

20220225 13:09:58 INF Environment passes all checks!

Environment looks good, you are ready to go!

Done. Made 2907 targets from 236 files in 1246ms
ninja: Entering directory `./out/python_lib'
ninja: error: unknown target 'python'
```